# Solr Multivalued fields to string

Tags: solr

I have a SOLR instance which is fed from a 3rd party application and one of the fields is multivalued and returns like Below

```
<arr name="site_code">
      <str>4A</str>
      <str>R3</str>
      <str>UK</str>
```

However another requirment is for the application to display the values as a comma separated list  `4A,R3,UK.`

I have tried to create a copyfield from site_code into a field call site_code_csv but it doesnt work.  Is there a way this can be done?

thanks

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get information out of Solr in the format `4A,R3,UK` you can simply change the output format in Solr for your individual query:

Add `wt=csv` (wt is "writer type/response format") to your query.

Documentation: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CSVResponseWriter